# PHP y Mysql, select e Insert o Update

Tags: php, mysql

Intento almacenar en una tabla datos de una consulta

Estoy trabajando con una tabla **clima_laboral_estructura** el ultimo registro de cada fila es una respuesta numérica decimal

Al momento de realizar el reporte, necesito extraer el total de respuestas que correspondan a un rango especifico

```
SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 )
```

Me gustaría insertarlo el resultado de esa consulta en una tabla clima_laboral_total en un registro Muy_en_Desacuerdo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He intentado almacenar el resultado en una variable, mas sin embargo aunque me muestra un numero en mysql, la consulta almacena el select entero, como si fuese un parrafo

```
$result = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5;");
```

---

También intento hacer un **UPDATE**

```
$Update = ("UPDATE clima_laboral_total SET muy_en_desacuerdo WHERE (SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 ))");
```

O **INSERT INTO**

a la Tabla clima_laboral_total SET Muy_en_Desacuerdo del SELECT mas estos me arrojan error, por el **SELECT  SUM**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sinceramente, no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal - de tantas cosas - o que deberia hacer para que funcione de manera correcta

```html
<?php

$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cencolpsoft");

mysqli_select_db($enlace, "clima_laboral_estructura");

if (!$enlace) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

//echo "Éxito: Se realizó una conexión apropiada a MySQL! La base de datos mi_bd es genial." . PHP_EOL;
//echo "Información del host: " . mysqli_get_host_info($enlace) . PHP_EOL;


//Toma todos las respuestas almacenadas con un valor menor a 1.5 y las suma

$sql = mysqli_query($enlace"UPDATE clima_laboral_total 
SET muy_en_desacuerdo = (SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) 
                         FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle 
                         WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 )
                        )");


//$consulta = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5;");

//Cuenta 
//$consulta2 = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clima_laboral_estructura WHERE Total_Respuesta  <1.5");


//tomar los resultados y realizar una operacion aritmetica de division 

//Usar el resultado google chart bar stacked Linea 51


mysqli_close($enlace);
?>
<section class="page">
    
    <div  class="">
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="row ">
                
                <div class="col-md-12 comp-grid">
                     <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultSeries);

function drawMultSeries() {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Valores', 'Muy En Desacuerdo', 'En Desacuerdo', 'De Acuerdo', 'Muy de Acuerdo', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        //Lugar donde usar los valores obtenios en linea 18  a 27
        ['Clima Laboral Estructura', 10, 24, 20, 32, ''],
        
        
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 1200,
        height: 150,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: 'percent'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</section>
<section>


</section>
```

Comment: Hola, en tu cláusla `UPDATE` no asignas el valor al campo. Debes asignar el valor asi: `UPDATE table SET campo = valor WHERE ...`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Realmente no entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Quieres actualizar todas las filas de la tabla? ¿Quieres insertar? Tampoco entiendo el resultado que obtienes: *mas sin embargo aunque me muestra un numero en mysql, la consulta almacena el select entero, como si fuese un parrafo*  ¿?

Comment: Gracias, muy educado, normalmente borran cualquier apartado de buenos modales y dejan solo la respuesta concreta. Con respecto al tema tengo que actualizar los 4 registros, sin embargo, cada registro debe ser actualizado de manera diferente, ya que cada uno almacenara las respuestas de la 1ra tabla filtradas.

Comment: Si el problema, como parece ser, está a nivel de PHP, debes mostrar el código PHP completo. Con la sola consulta poco podemos hacer, hay que ver cómo la ejecutas. Debes explicar también **cuál es el criterio por el que se decidirá qué registro actualizar**. Ninguna de las respuestas dadas lo especifica porque en la pregunta no dices nada sobre eso.

Comment: Listo, agregado el codigo, mas que todo los datos a actualizar iban a ser usado en ese grafico, pero como comente arriba, por alguna razon No me deja almacenar el resultado de la consulta en una variable. por lo que he optado por actualizar una tabla total, con dichas consultas y despues tomar los datos de la tabla y hacer un fetch array con ellas en el grafico.

Comment: No entendí lo que quisiste explicar en el comentario, pero sí estoy seguro de que se puede hacer mejor... Almacenar unos resultados en variables es de lo más fácil, pero habría que mirar como lo intentabas. En cuanto al código, el error que veo es que te falta una coma entre la conexión y la sentencia SQL: `$sql = mysqli_query($enlace,"UPDATE clima_laboral_total 
SET muy_en_desacuerdo = (SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) 
                         FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle 
                         WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 )
                        )");`

Comment: UPDATE
    clima_laboral_total
SET
    `Muy_en_Desacuerdo` =(
    SELECT
        SUM(
            clima_laboral_estructura.Total_Respuesta
        )
    FROM
        clima_laboral_estructura AS clima_laboral_estructura
    WHERE
        (
            clima_laboral_estructura.Total_Respuesta < 1.5
        ) 


gracias pero me da error en el where, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 2):

Sobre el error que comentas veo que tu update esta incorrecto es por el WHERE te esta mandando el error.

original:

> UPDATE clima_laboral_total SET muy_en_desacuerdo **WHERE** (SELECT 
>   SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE 
>   (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 ))

modificado:

> UPDATE clima_laboral_total SET muy_en_desacuerdo (SELECT 
>   SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE
>   (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 ) )

y sobre este punto

> $result = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM
>   clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5;");

te recomiendo que la lógica por el momento la realices en la base de datos por Procedimientos almacenados te dejo una liga donde puedas apoyarte a crearlos

https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2290-procedimientos-almacenados-y-triggers-en-mysql/.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, hice pruebas y  arroja exactamente el mismo error . #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM `clima_laboral_total` WHERE (SELECT SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_lab' en la linea 1

Comment: La consulta sigue siendo errónea: no hay asignación con `SET = campo`... tampoco se indica el criterio que ha de seguirse para saber qué fila de la tabla se va a actualizar. Este `UPDATE` cambiaría todas las filas de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo mal el UPDATE. No estas asignando valor al campo que cambia.

Prueba así

```
UPDATE clima_laboral_total 
SET muy_en_desacuerdo = (SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) 
                         FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle 
                         WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 )
                        )
```

Comment: Muy atento con esa consulta: ¡va a cambiar todos los valores de la columna en todas las filas! ¿Es eso lo que se quiere realmente? ¿Por qué no tiene un `WHERE`  la parte del `UPDATE`.  Creo que son cosas que se deben preguntar al OP.

Comment: No, un registro individual, por eso lo mencione, que sera Muy en Desacuerdo, ya que los otros registros se actualizan y muestran en otro reporte.

Comment: Jdev, prove el código


UPDATE
    clima_laboral_total
SET
    muy_en_desacuerdo =(
    SELECT
        SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta)
    FROM
        clima_laboral_estructura AS cle
    WHERE
        (cle.Total_Respuesta < 1.5)
)
#1264 - Out of range value for column 'Muy_en_Desacuerdo' at row 6

Answer (score 0):

agradezco mucho las sugerencias y apoyo con respecto al tema, al final como no pude encontrar forma mediante este metodo opte por

```
$Consulta1 = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT  SUM(cle.Total_Respuesta) FROM clima_laboral_estructura AS cle WHERE  (cle.Total_Respuesta  <1.5 )");
```

$total1 = mysqli_fetch_row($Consulta1);
echo "La cantidad de registros es: ".$total1[0];

con esto ya obtengo el valor de la consulta, por ahora.

Lo unico es que obtengo un array, que no puede usarse en funciones algoritmicas, y no el decimal. pero ya es un avance.